# Installing Manjaro 18 on HP Spectre NVMe SSD

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, manjaro, ssd, nvme

I recently picked up this lovely laptop ([HP Spectre X360 13](https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c06161949)), and want to install Manjaro on it. It has a Toshiba NVMe SSD (KXG50ZNV1T02).

Seeing that this will be my first install of Linux onto an SSD of any sort, I would just like the community's feedback regarding any special precaution I should be taking when installing to an NVMe drive, to maintain longevity of the drive? TRIM? Discards?

Closest machine I could find info on on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_Spectre_x360_-_13-ae005na) is a similarly-spec'd model, but no special mention of SSD considerations.

I will not be running a dual-boot setup ... Manjaro will be used exclusively.

Lastly, is there any special configuration/package needed to get full-speed Thunderbolt 3 support in Linux? Or is this not needed?

Comment: Did you try to install it? Any error shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **SSD/NVMe**, I strongly suggest you to read Archwiki pages [1] and [2].
This is the starting point, rather, much more!
Talking about which filesystem to use for, take a look here [3] for example.

For **Thunderbolt**, I have no experience with this hardware, so my only advice is to start from the Archwiki as well.

A personal advice: since your hardware is really new, use always latest kernel.

---

[1] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive
[2] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/NVMe
[3] https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-50-filesystems